# Centering a widget horizontally and vertically in GWT + MGWT

Tags: gwt, layout, mobile, vertical-alignment, tablet

I'm trying to create the following layout for a mobile/tablet application using GWT + MGWT. I want the central widget to stay centred horizontally and vertically, but for the logo and lower text to fill up the remaining space.

[image: Mobile/Tablet layout]

This seems like it should be such a simple thing, but I just can't get it to work! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try with a VerticalPanel ?

```
VerticalPanel   vp = new VerticalPanel();

logo = new Label( "" );
vp.add( logo );
vp.setCellHorizontalAlignment(  logo , HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER) ;
vp.setCellVerticalAlignment(    logo , HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE) ;

 ... 
 and so on for others.
```

Comment: Hi Overnuts, thanks for the response. I haven't tried it exactly like that, no. Are you supposed to set the alignment before or after adding it to the panel? You seem to have done both :-)

Comment: in a first time, add it to the panel, and then set alignments !

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I was trying to do with within an MGWT ScrollPanel widget, which really doesn't work as expected. Your suggestion works fine in a normal situation though.